# WARNING: Can't exec "git": No such file or directory at /home/git/bin/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm line 152

Tags: gitolite

```
git clone git@127.0.0.1:gitolite-admin.git
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
WARNING: Can't exec "git": No such file or directory at /home/git/bin/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm line 152, <DATA> line 1.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes from [`sitaramc/gitolite/src/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/ef9ab68412cbee93c24eb920dbabbb6daa8b1c08/src/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm#L152), and can be seen for instance in [this issue](https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc/issues/517#issuecomment-17513529).

You need to check the `PATH`, with the Git installation folder in it: `/path/to/Git/bin`.